# matrix multiplication question

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A,B, and C be matrices of size $l \times m,m  \times n$ and  $n \times p$ .In which order should be the triple product $ABC$ be computed, so as to minimize the number of multiplication required?

Comment: You have to do it in the order written, or they cannot be multiplied.

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla There are two ways to compute it assuming the only thing we can do at once is multiply two matrices: (AB)C or A(BC).

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you're wondering whether you should do $(AB)C$ or $A(BC)$. Using naive matrix multiplication,

$AB$ takes $m(ln)$ multiplications resulting in an $l \times n$ matrix, and so $(AB)C$ then takes $n(lp)$ multiplications, whereas

$BC$ takes $n(mp)$ multiplications resulting in an $m \times p$ matrix, and so $A(BC)$ then takes $m(lp)$ multiplications.

So, using naive multiplication, compare $lmn + lnp$ and $mnp + lmp$ and go for the lesser.